# How I can access the values from a form made via Reactbootstrap when a user clicks submit button, am I unable to grab the values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, react-bootstrap

This is the code I am currently working with. So what is the way to collect the values from Form? 
In the submitHandler, how can I see the values from email,query,and fullName.
I am accustomed to onChange way but is there a way to grab the values solely using onSubmitHandler ?

```
import React, { Fragment, FormEventHandler } from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from '../../../components';

const ContactForm = () => {

  const submitHandler: FormEventHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.persist();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Reach out to us !</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId="formGridEmail">
          <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control placeholder="Peter Pots" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Label>Your Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="sample@something.com" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formGridQuery">
          <Form.Label>Query</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} placeholder="Peter Pots" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" icon="arrow-circle-right">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add attribute `name` with unique names to `Form.Control` components:

```js
import React, { Fragment, FormEventHandler,  } from 'react';
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from '../../../components';

const ContactForm = () => {

  const [values, setValues] = useState({});

  const onFormChange = (e, updatedAt) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });
    console.log(name, value);
  };

  const submitHandler: FormEventHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.persist();
    console.log('push data somewhere :)')
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Reach out to us !</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group controlId="formGridEmail">
          <Form.Label>Full Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control name="full_name" onChange={onFormChange} placeholder="Peter Pots" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Label>Your Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" name="email" onChange={onFormChange} placeholder="sample@something.com" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formGridQuery">
          <Form.Label>Query</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control as="textarea" name="query" onChange={onFormChange} rows={3} placeholder="Peter Pots" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit" icon="arrow-circle-right">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: Thankyou @Pavel for your answer but I get this error `Property 'name' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' ` at event.target.value     .Also I have a query about what's the use case of control-id ?

Comment: I'm really sorry it's my fault. I'll update my answer in one minute.

Comment: what's the use of control id and is there a way to achieve this feat without onChange and solely using onSubmitHandler.

Comment: Of course we can. But it’s not a React way. On submit event we can collect data from field some another way for example using vanilla js with HTMLDom Element manipulations. I’m not recommend to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should use FormData object. You have to pass there form from event.target.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      return;
    }
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const data = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
    console.dir(data);
    push your data somewhere...
};
```

You will see object with properties named like your form controls with values inside your form.

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Row className="mb-2">
    <Col md="3">
      <Form.Group controlId="fromItem1">
        <Form.Label>Form item 1</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          name="name1"
          required
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter data"
          defaultValue={defaultValue1}
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </Col>
    <Col md="3">
      <Form.Group controlId="formItem2">
        <Form.Label>Form Item 2</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          name="name2"
          required
          type="number"
          placeholder="Enter data"
          defaultValue={defaultValue2}
        />
      </Form.Group>
    </Col>
    ...
    <Col md="3">
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Form>
```

Hope it helps!